# Slow down strobe on light

Tags: resistance

I have a flashlight with a strobe mode and need to know how to slow down the strobe on it. Please tell me if I should add a resistor or vary the power source to slow and NOT dim the strobe light.

Comment: A very hand wavey question. But the answer you're looking for is: you need to reprogram the micro controller that is in the device.

Comment: Show us a schematic of the flashlight circuit, and take out the part about flashlights. Then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, since these kinds of functions on flashlights are usually controlled by microcontroller and not by discrete electronics. At least I have never seen one where that was the case.